# How can i assign testing role using azure active directory authentication

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am using azure active directory for authentication and i already add roles to it and assign user to his role.

for testing i need to set the role manually throug my code 
so is there a way to achive that ??

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would imagine this would require you to create an [AppRoleAssignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity) targeting the proper role in your app. You can see which properties are needed by looking at the Supports column and find the ones that say POST. 3 required properties: id = id of role, principalId = objectId of user, resourceId = objectId of the service principal of the app.

Comment: You can do that using Graph API - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations#AddDirectoryRoleMembers